# window.location.href in javascript just reloading page, not navigating to another website

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to navigate from my website to another website using a button, here is my code, I am using React Bootstrap with this project

```
<button onclick="window.location.href = 'https://www.glassdoor.com';">Click Here</button>
```

However, when I click it, it does not navigate to the new website, it only reloads the homepage of the website I am on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The page will strangely refresh when I click the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681646/the-page-will-strangely-refresh-when-i-click-the-button)

Comment: Also, since you're using [Bootstrap, just use an anchor tag](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#button-tags): `<a class="btn etc" href="glassdoor-url-here">Click</a>`

Answer (score 3):

`window.location.href` returns the href (URL) of the current page

So you can remove the `href` part and simply set the value of the url you wish to navigate to.

```html
    <button onclick="window.location = 'https://www.glassdoor.com'">Click Here</button>
```

Failing that you can also use the function `assign`

```html
<button onclick="window.location.assign('https://www.glassdoor.com')">Click Here</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I am getting an issue with both solutions though. If I put quotation marks around the whole function, the button does not do anything, however, without the quotation marks, it executes automatically without the button being clicked

Comment: post updated code please. The above should work fine. I recommend the `window.location =`

Comment: I found the problem with my code, some syntactical problems. Thank you very much!